# how to customize ngxbootstrap daterangepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap, angular16

I'm using ngx bootstrap datepicker i have a requirement to show multiple date range is calender.when  open calender view should be  months which show selected multiple months.on click that selected month it show selected dates in that month.
[image]

when click on one particular month selected days in that month have to show

[image]

so after refering  https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview
I created bsdaterange picker with minmode'month' but not able to show dates when click on a particular month.

```
                                <input  class="input-box form-control datePicker" #dp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker
                                    [readonly]="true" [bsValue]="value.bsRangeValue"     [datesEnabled]="value.datesEnabled"
                                    [bsConfig]="{rangeInputFormat : 'DD.MM.YYYY',minMode: 'month',displayMonths:1}" name="mydate"
                                     (onShown)="onOpenCalendar($event,value)" (bsValueChange)="dateRangeChange($event)" 
                                    >
```

Is there any solution in ngxbootstrap  to fullfill this requirement